# JLS 12.4.1 difficulty in understanding

Tags: java, jls

In JLS, it is written like: ***A class or interface type T*** .

My question is what does the above like means ?
 does it mean:  **interface** **a < T >**

Can anyone please explain the line below with example ?

> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> - T is a class and an instance of T is created.
> - T is a class and a static method declared by T is invoked.

Thanks in advance

For more details: 
As per Section 12.4.1 given here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html

A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the first occurrence of any one of the following:

T is a class and an instance of T is created.

T is a class and a static method declared by T is invoked.

A static field declared by T is assigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A class or interface type T

It just means `T` is "some class or interface". Just like `x` in maths is used to mean "some number".

> T is a class and an instance of T is created.

Say you have a class, `Foo`. `Foo` will be initialized immediate before `new Foo()`, if not already initialized.

> T is a class and a static method declared by T is invoked.

Say that `Foo` has a static method `bar`. `Foo` will be initialized immediate before `Foo.bar()`, if not already initialized.

---

Example `Foo` class:

```
class Foo {
  static void bar() {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> A class or interface type T

*This means:* In the following text, any time we say T, we're referring to a `class` or an `interface`.